# Apache analytics with virtual hosts

Tags: apache-httpd, logs, apache-virtualhost

I've found various open-source tools (such as [goaccess.io](http://goaccess.io)) that can turn an `access.log` or `other_vhosts_access.log` into a unique visitors analytics:

```
  739 visits 16/Oct/2016 
  804 visits 15/Oct/2016 
  838 visits 14/Oct/2016 
  966 visits 13/Oct/2016
```

but as my `other_vhosts_access.log` contains virtual hosts:

```
www.siteb.com:80 216.244.x.x - - [17/Oct/2016:07:26:23 +0200] "GET ...
www.siteb.com:80 206.14.x.x - - [17/Oct/2016:07:26:23 +0200] "GET ...
www.sitec.com:80 189.18.x.x - - [17/Oct/2016:07:21:43 +0200] "GET ...
```

are there analytics tools that provide per-host details like this :

```
  739 visits 16/Oct/2016 
   |--- sitea.com   140
   |--- siteb.com   127
   |--- sitec.com   472
  804 visits 15/Oct/2016 
   |--- sitea.com   205
   |--- siteb.com   120
   |--- sitec.com   479
```

?

Comment: https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/analog-vs-awstats-vs-webalizer-if-i-had-to-choose-one.15893/

Comment: I'd try: `awk '$1~/siteb/' access.log | goaccess --log-format=VCOMBINED`